# subsection title in header in twosided article

Tags: header-footer

I wish to have section and subsection title in header on every page. Here is my code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead{}     
\fancyhead[RE]{\sl{\MakeUppercase{\rightmark}}}     
\fancyhead[LO]{\sl{\MakeUppercase{\rightmark}}}    
\fancyhead[RO]{\sl{\MakeUppercase{\leftmark}}}  
\fancyhead[LE]{\sl{\MakeUppercase{\leftmark}}} 
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\begin{document}               
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection} 
\newpage
\section{Second section}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\newpage
\subsection{Third subsection}
\end{document}
```

but on the pages with sections there are only sections title in header (for example "First section" on the right side on the page 1 but no "First subsection" on the left side). However on the page 3 it is correctly. Any solutions for this problem? Thanks.

Comment: The duplicate isn't  the same problem, because I have twosided article. I know that this works in onesided articles and I want to extend it to twosided.